# How to debug the entry-point of fork-exec process in GDB?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I have a C linux application (A) that spawns another process (P) when it is started. When I want to debug P I start A as usual and I connect with ddd/gdb to P.

Problems appear when I want to debug the entry-point (start of main) of P. If I follow the usual approach when I connect the debugger to P is already to late. The solution I've found was to insert a sleep at the begining of the main of P so I have time to connect with gdb but this is not a very elegant solution.

I've also tried using `asm("int $3")` but it doesn't seems to work.

Do you have any idea how I could solve this problem? (preferably without altering the code of A or P)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use this option:

```
set follow-fork-mode mode
```

Where *mode* is one of `parent`, `child` or `ask`.

To follow the parent (this is the default) use:

```
set follow-fork-mode parent
```

To follow the child:

```
set follow-fork-mode child
```

To have the debugger ask you each time:

```
set follow-fork-mode ask
```

So basically you'd start out connecting gdb to A, then set gdb to follow the child, and then when A spawns P, gdb will connect to P and detach from A.

Comment: `set follow-fork-mode ask` has been removed. According to [GDB's manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html#Debugging-Forks), the only options that are currently available are `parent` and `child`.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica I noticed that too. Any idea on why is that ?

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the [Nathan Fellman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/377295/441652), *catchpoints* come in handy, i.g.:

```
catch exec
```

Catchpoint works as a breakpoint. Every time a call to *exec()* syscall is detected, GDB stops. This allows you to set any breakpoint (i.g. `break main`) in any newly loaded executable before continuing. Another catchpoint `catch fork` works similarly for *fork()* syscall detection.

It is especially convenient:

- when both parent and child has to be followed (`set detach-on-fork off`);
- when parent processes forks often loading various executables.

Answer (score 1):

**`exec` part with `file` + `break main`**

The fork was part was explained at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/377295/895245

Now for the `exec`:

a.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    execl("./b", "./b", "ab", "cd", (char*)NULL);
    return 1;
}
```

b.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv ) {
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
}
```

Then:

```
gcc -g a.c -o a
gcc -g b.c -o b
gdb -nh -q a
```

Now on the interactive session:

```
Reading symbols from a...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4004ea: file a.c, line 4.
Starting program: /home/ciro/test/gdb-exec/a 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at a.c:4
4           execl("./b", "./b", "ab", "cd", (char*)NULL);
(gdb) file b
A program is being debugged already.
Are you sure you want to change the file? (y or n) y
Load new symbol table from "b"? (y or n) y
Reading symbols from b...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4004f5: file b.c, line 4.
(gdb) n

Breakpoint 2, main (argc=0, argv=0x7fffffffa570) at b.c:4
4               printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
(gdb) n
process 4877 is executing new program: /home/ciro/test/gdb-exec/b

Breakpoint 2, main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffa598) at b.c:4
4               printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
(gdb) n
ab
5               printf("%s\n", argv[2]);
(gdb) n
cd
6       }
(gdb)
```

You just have to make sure that you go up to the `exec` before running file, possibly with a `b execl`, since after that you will be using symbols from the new file.

Tested in Ubuntu 14.04, gdb 7.7.1.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do this by making use of gdb's remote debugging features, specifically `gdbserver`. In effect, launch (P) using `gdbserver`. These links have more detailed info:

- [Using gdbserver](http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/GDB/gdb_17.html)
- [GDB Remote Debugging](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb_18.html)

Comment: gdbserver allows remote debugging but does not solve the problem at hand, which is more a case of how GDB follows fork/clone.

Comment: I don't think this is a case for remote debugging.  It's more about which process gdb follows on a fork.

Answer (score -1):

set a break point at main(), it will also break at main() of the execed program.