# How to create a process on Mac OS using fork() and exec()

Tags: c, macos, process, exec, fork

I am working on a relatively simple, independent "*process starter*" that I would like to get to work on Windows (XP, Vista, 7), Linux (Ubuntu 10.10) and especially **Mac OS X** (10.6). Linux and Windows basically work, but I'm having some trouble with the Mac version.
I was hoping `fork()` and `exec()` functions would work the same way under Mac OS as they work in Linux. So my first question is:

1. **Should I use these to create a
   process on the Mac or are there any
   platform specific functions to be
   used?**

My current code (which worked fine under Linux) to debug this looks something like this:

```
pid_t processId = 0;
if (processId = fork()) == 0)
{
    const char * tmpApplication = "/Path/to/TestApplication";

    int argc = 1;
    char * argv[argc + 1];

    argv[0] = tmpApplication;
    argv[1] = NULL;

    execv(tmpApplication, argv);
}else
{
    //[...]
}
```

**Any idea if this could work under Mac OS X as well, because my child process is simply not being launched, while there are no errors that would come up.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following program, adapted from your code, works just fine for me under OS X:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main (void) {
    pid_t processId;
    if ((processId = fork()) == 0) {
        char app[] = "/bin/echo";
        char * const argv[] = { app, "success", NULL };
        if (execv(app, argv) < 0) {
            perror("execv error");
        }
    } else if (processId < 0) {
        perror("fork error");
    } else {
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

I suggest you start with this simple fragment, and if it works keep adding things until you find what makes it break.

Comment: ok - I think I know what my problem is now, I actually tried to access memory in the parent process (to look up the actual child process name), which seems to fail miserably - any suggestion how I would do this? to be more clear: I need to access an arbitrary application name after calling `fork()` to pass it to the `execv()` command.

Comment: @Chris You probably ought to create a new question about that problem and illustrate it with a code sample. I, for one, am not sure I understood what you are doing.

Comment: it was just a bug in my code in the end, which I fixed now - thanks for your assistance - the example was really helpful!

Comment: As the man page for 'fork' (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/fork.2.html) says:

`LEGACY SYNOPSIS
     #include <sys/types.h>
     #include <unistd.h>
The include file <sys/types.h> is necessary.`
Maybe it was that.

Answer (score 5):

Is `TestApplication` an actual executable, or an application bundle (.app)? You can only launch actual executables using functions like `execv()`. Usually the executable inside an application bundle can be found at `ApplicationName.app/Contents/MacOS/ApplicationName`.

Comment: thank you Justin - but TestApplication is a "plain" unix executable that I build myself and also use under Windows & Linux without issues - so it is not an application bundle :(

Comment: To answer your original question, both `fork()` and `execv()` are perfectly fine to use. What does `strerror()` say after you try your `execv()`?

Comment: hmm - I don't really know, since execv() will be executed in the child process & I don't really know how I could debug that part inside the if statement of the above code

Comment: I tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377195/how-to-debug-the-entry-point-of-fork-exec-process[1] but it didn't work

Comment: The child process will inherit the parent's file descriptors, and this should include `stdout`, `stderr`, etc., so you might be able to do this: `fprintf(stderr, "Could not create child process: %s\n", strerror(errno))`