# How to execute line of C code without waiting for result?

Tags: c, multithreading, asynchronous, nonblocking

I've written a command line program in C that is invoked by shell scripts. The last API call in [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer/blob/6f0b2e0bcece033dd9c8d19b2a7a2015066a4878/displayplacer.c#L164) instantly applies the desired changes but takes up to 10 seconds to return. How can I execute this line without waiting for the result? My intention is to invoke `CGCompleteDisplayConfiguration()` and then exit the program immediately so that the following lines in the parent shell scripts are not unnecessarily paused for 10 seconds.

Something like this would be ideal:

```
isSuccess = someCode() && isSuccess;

CGCompleteDisplayConfiguration(configRef, kCGConfigurePermanently); //non-blocking

if (isSuccess) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Run it in the backgroung

Comment: If I understand you right, you want your C programme to *exit* while the task is still not completed? If so, you'd need to create a child process ([`fork`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) on linux or `CreateProcess`, if on Windows). Doesn't seem the right approach to me, though. Preferrably send the programme as a whole to background already from your shell (e. g. [linux](https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/) or [windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/35305/cmd-exe-how-to-start-a-background-process-run-some-things-stop-background-pro)).

Comment: Running the entire program in the background isn't ideal since the first few seconds of execution time re-arrange the users monitors on macOS. The last API call is the one I don't want to wait to complete.

Comment: A program which pretends to be done but still does something in the background... Is this a good idea? Immediately, the situation pops in my mind: User is in hurry and starts your program. Program is done. User is satisfied and switchs off the computer...

Comment: I am fully aware this is a hack. I would like to experiment with the approach though.

Comment: MacOS supports `fork` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4327062/1312382)) as well. Instead of calling `execv` like there, you'd just call the function in question. Just make sure you call it in the child process (result of `fork` == 0) and parent can return afterwards.

Comment: Make your program a kernel daemon ?

Comment: @Aconcagua Your link is helpful, but for some reason doesn't work in this situation. Calling CGCompleteDisplayConfiguration() on the child thread kills the child thread and does nothing.