# gdb debugging process after exec call

Tags: gdb, exec

I don't know how to debug after the process after calling `execle`. I've looked at other websites and some suggested using `set fork-follow-mode child`, which helped me get into the fork. However, after the fork, I exit into the main function and never get into the program I am exec'ing.

Here is the code:

```
            } else if (!(pid_T2 = fork())) {
                char **env = NULL;
                char *units_env = NULL;
                char *sleep_env = NULL;
                size_t sleep_sz = 16;

                env = (char **) malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
                sleep_env = (char *) malloc(sleep_sz * sizeof(char));
                snprintf(sleep_env, sleep_sz, "TSTALL=%d", cmd_args->sleep_num);
                if (cmd_args->kb) {
                        units_env = "UNITS=1";
                } else {
                        units_env = "UNITS=0";
                }
                *(env) = units_env; *(env + 1) = sleep_env; *(env + 2) = "TMOM=0";

                /*printf("%s %s\n", *(env), *(env + 1));*/

                close(pipe_A2toT2[1]);
                dup2(pipe_A2toT2[0], 0);
                close(pipe_A2toT2[0]);

                execle("totalsize", "totalsize", NULL, env); //Exits to main after this line, never goes into program.
          }
```

I know that the process image gets replaced by exec call, however why am I still exiting to this program's main instead of going into `totalsize` program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make gdb follow execv? Not working despite "follow-exec-mode"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671229/how-to-make-gdb-follow-execv-not-working-despite-follow-exec-mode)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Here is the code:

That's not *the* code. That's an un-compilable and meaningless snippet of the code.
You also didn't tell what OS you are using, or which GDB commands you used.

Here is an example showing how this is *supposed* to work, on Linux:

// echo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[0]) {
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
    if (i != 1) printf(" ");
    printf("%s", argv[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

// exec.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  pid_t pid = fork();
  int status;

  if (pid == 0) {
    execlp("./echo", "echo", "aa", "bb", (char*)0);
    abort();
  } else {
    printf("parent %d waiting for %d\n", getpid(), pid);
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    printf("child %d exited %d\n", pid, status);
  }
  return status;
}
```

Now let's compile this all and run under GDB:

```
gcc -g -std=c99 -o echo echo.c
gcc -g -o exec exec.c

gdb -q ./exec
Reading symbols from ./exec...done.
(gdb) set follow-fork-mode child
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4006a5: file exec.c, line 9.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/exec 

Breakpoint 1, main () at exec.c:9
9         pid_t pid = fork();
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[New process 9851]
```

Note how GDB attached new program above, because `follow-fork-mode` told it to.

```
parent 9832 waiting for 9851
process 9851 is executing new program: /tmp/echo
```

Note how GDB noticed that the process is executing a new binary.

```
[Switching to process 9851]

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffe8d8) at echo.c:4
4         for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
```

Note that we are now stopped in a *different* `main`.

Comment: "That's an un-compilable and meaningless snippet of the code" mean Russian haha. One should also look into `follow-exec-mode`.