# Debug fork() in eclipse cdt

Tags: c, eclipse, gdb, fork, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to debug some fork() mechanism with eclipse cdt (Juno).
I wrote the program in C.

```
  if( -1 == (pid = fork()) ) /* error */
    goto cleanup;
  else if ( 0 == pid ) /* child */
  {
    execlp("gcc", "gcc", cFilePath, "-o" , GCC_OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, NULL);
    goto cleanup; /* Arrives here only on error! */
  }
  else if (pid > 0) /* parent - checks: correct pid returns, returns normally, with exit status = 0*/
  {
      returnedpid = wait(exitStatus);
      if( pid != returnedpid || exitStatus == NULL || !WIFEXITED(*exitStatus) || !WEXITSTATUS(*exitStatus) )
          goto cleanup;
  }
```

I tried to add "`set follow-fork-mode child`" as said here: http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.programmer/2006-02/msg00435.html

**1. How can I debug the code section where `(0==pid)`?**

**2. When I get to the wait statement, the debugger just return immediately, isn't wait() suppose to suspend till the child returns? Why is it return immediately?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problems are probably due to "detach-on-fork" being set to off. DSF sets this by default (it's also gdb's default).

1) Put a breakpoint onto lines with "execlp..." and "returnedpid =...".
2) In debug configuration enable "non-stop mode" and "automatically debug forked process".
3) Start debug session. You will hit a breakpoint either in child or parent. Now see debug view.

[image: Debug view]

You will notice your binary shows two threads.

4) Click on one or the other (lines with main() in above image) to switch debug context.

Comment: Hi dbrank0. I followed your example and find it working (but you need to force the "Automatically debug forked process" option) but with a problem anyway. I'm "daemonizing" my process so, following gurus indication, I'm forking twice. It seems to me that the first fork is followed properly but as soon as I try to fork the second time the whole debugger hangs and I can't follow none of the two processes. thanks anyway but... any Idea?

Comment: No, sorry, but do look if any of switches explained in "debugging forks" chapter (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html) helps.

Comment: Works perfectly, even follows execvp (swapn new process) after fork. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because the init process reaps the child before you go to wait. Try blocking sigchld as you go into fork and then unblock the signals after your forks/execs. Maybe that should give you some idea as to what is exactly happening.

Using sigprocmask should help you.

Answer (score 1):

1. In debug configuration window -> Debugger -> Check "Automatically debug forked processes"
2. Open breakpoint window -> View menu -> Add Event Breakpoint C/C++ -> "fork
   called"
3. Now once the event breakpoint occurred, press F6 -> you'll see new process in debug window
4. Choose new process and press F6 -
   You are in the child
5. Enjoy

Comment: thanks! note that the UI is kinda bad so you may not see check boxes. Just click the text to enable the debug forked processes.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the perfect answer of @dbrank0, the Debug Configuration window is located under the Run menu. You can find the mentioned configurations under the Debugger tab.
[image]